# Statistic estimation of total nodes in a tree where edge traversal is expensive

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, statistics, duplicates

I have a directed tree, and I would like to get its size. I have no information about its depth or distribution of nodes. There are two major obstacles:

1) The tree is very large (~billions of nodes)

2) Edge traversal is expensive.

Are there statistical methods I can use to get an estimate of its size (number of nodes) quickly and with bounded error? Unfortunately, googling just results in exact-count algorithms which would perform poorly given these restrictions.

**Bonus**

If I relax the constraint from tree to DAG (directed acyclic graph), can I get both its size and number of unique paths? E.g. for this DAG (every edge points down)

[image]

There are 19 nodes (size) and 23 paths (4 extra ones because the red edge gives 1 more path for its destination node and 3 more paths to the children of its destination node)

**Things I've tried**

For the tree case, I am thinking of something along the lines of:

```
amounts = []
def estimateHelper(node):
    amounts[node.depth].push(len(node.children))
    for each child in small random sample of node.children:
        estimateHelper(child)
def estimate(root):
    estimateHelper(root)
    reach = 0
    for (j = len(amounts) - 1; j >= 0; --j):
        avgChildrenPerNodeAtThisLevel = avg(amounts[j])
        reach = avgChildrenPerNodeAtThisLevel + avgChildrenPerNodeAtThisLevel * reach
    return reach
```

It essentially computes the "reach" at the deepest nodes of the tree, then propagates that back into the level above to find the reach at that level. It does that until it eventually finds the "reach" of the root of the tree. I'm not sure if I'm making any assumptions about a uniform distribution of nodes or not in the above algorithm. To reiterate, I don't know what kind of distribution a given tree will have.

Assuming it works, this also solves the "paths" for the DAG. Once you have all the "paths", I am thinking of using the inverse of the birthday paradox to figure out how many unique nodes there are. Birthday paradox answers "how many days (paths) do we need to choose until we hit a duplicate day with some probability given 365 unique days of the year". So we keep trying random paths (days) until we hit a duplicate node, we repeat that several times to find a probability for that event, and then we plug it into the birthday paradox to find the number of unique nodes (unique days in the year). Note though, that the birthday paradox also makes an assumption of uniformity.

None of this is very rigorous. What would be ideal is something that gives me an estimate with an error bound, and a paper that describes the algorithm with sufficient rigor. Any pointers in the right direction are very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *get its size*? Count the number of nodes? Is there a limit in the number of children of a given node? You could, for example, go a step behind and try another approach: how is this tree built? Perhaps you can store a counter and increment it on each insert and decrement it on each removal? Maybe storing additional information as you build it is what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Filipe. The size is the number of nodes. There is no real limit of how many children a node has, but a practical limit of about 100,000. The tree is not built by me, but by a large number of distributed servers. I'd like to estimate the size locally (on my laptop) and quickly, and the edge traversal is expensive because for each node I need to do a network request to the appropriate server.

Comment: Try to validate your algorithm: run it 100 times and calculate its 
relative dispersion. Also try different avg-s (quadratic mean, geometric mean, etc.), and tweak the sample size.

Comment: @SergiuToarca you can't traverse nodes, and you can't get any additional info about tree from servers, but you have average count of childrens for each node (AVG). It's awful situation) If you can get the total size of tree in KB or MB (TOTAL) - calculate the count of nodes by division TOTAL/(NODESZ + AVG * CHILDSZ). It will be upper bound of estimation (if AVG is ok).

Comment: I don't think you can have bounded error unless you look at every possible path. What if the path that you don't look at has ten times as many nodes as the whole rest of the tree?

Comment: @Kicsi I tried doing this to see if the "inverse birthday paradox" method above worked (for a set rather than a tree). However, I found that the number of samples that I needed to run to get a good estimate was coming close to just running the full tree. I think that it's possible to improve by using more than just the first duplicate. This would give you a distribution rather than a single point. I didn't try it in the hopes that somebody else would have an answer.

Comment: @Aaron Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant a statistical error bound. E.g. 95% chance of being within 10.5bn and 10.8bn nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knuth wrote a paper on this in the context of backtracking tree search: Estimating the efficiency of backtrack programs - e.g. http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-129/S0025-5718-1975-0373371-6/S0025-5718-1975-0373371-6.pdf. Search terms Knuth tree estimate also find papers referencing this such as ftp://ftp.cs.indiana.edu/pub/techreports/TR60.pdf and http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hutter/EARG.shtml/earg/stack/WS06-11-005.pdf.

I have no idea how this would translate to DAGs in general, but - again in the context of tree search - you may be able to redefine DAGs as trees with the same number of vertices by adding constraints that disallow edges entering each vertex after he first. E.g. when choosing a subset of numbers one by one, require that they be listed in ascending order - then (1,3,8) has only the single ancestor (1,3).

Come to think of it, you could also define a tree in which each DAG path to an edge defined a different edge in the tree. Counting the number of edges in this might tell you something about the number of DAG paths.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I wanted for the tree case! I'm going to hold out on awarding the answer in case somebody can find a solution for the DAG case (I'm also looking through all the references).

Comment: Thanks - I did have a thought about defining trees with the same number of vertices as a given DAG which might work in some circumstances and I have added this as an edit.